# How would I evaluate the limit of a function at $x = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am in Calculus 1, and I have the following limit to evaluate:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + \alpha|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}}$$

How would I find the values for $\alpha$ and $\beta\in\mathbb R$ such that the limit also exists in $\mathbb R$. How would one evaluate such a limit?

I have tried factoring out x from both the numerator and denominator, (I suppose that you're allowed to do that even with an absolute value for x) and then I am left with

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}}}$$

But I am unsure of how to continue

How can I evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}$ ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Please, provide more context to your question, that way people see you've put effort into your question and will be more likely to help you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we assume that $\beta\geq0$. If this werent the case the expression $\sqrt{x^2+\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}$ is not defined for sufficiently small $x$.

That being said, let's divide by $|x|$ and we end up with

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \underbrace{\frac{|x|\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}}}}_{=:f(x)}$$

Now let us inspect the single terms. $|x|\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is unproblematic since it is the product of a bounded function and a function that converges to $0$ and thus the product also converges to $0$. However $\frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}$ oscillates and there is no damping that would ensure its convergence.
Thus our mathematical intuition tells us that we should try to prove that the functions converges if $\beta=0$ and does not converge otherwise. (Keep in mind we have just built up our intuition so far!)

**Case 1:  $\beta=0$**
In this case the expressions simplifies to

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{|x|\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0} |x|\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + \alpha=\alpha$$

**Case 2:  $\beta>0$** In this case we try to find a series $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $x_n\to0$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge. Since we expect the oscillations to be the problem we choose
$$x_n=\frac{2}{\pi n}$$
which yields
$$
f(x_n)=\begin{cases}\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\beta(n\pi/2)^2}} &\mbox{ for $n$ even}\\
\pm\tfrac{2}{n\pi}+\alpha &\mbox{ for $n$ uneven}
\end{cases}$$
Hence, for even $n$ the functions tends to $0$, whereas for uneven $n$ the function tends towards $\alpha$. So we have proven that for $\alpha\neq0$ the expression can not converge. In contrary to our initial intuition we have to consider a third case, namely.

**Case 3:  $\beta>0$ and $\alpha=0$** We obsevere that $1\leq\sqrt{1+\frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}}$ and therefore $1\geq\sqrt{1+\frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}}^{-1}\geq0$. Hence,
$$
f(x)=  |x|\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{\beta|\cos(\frac{1}{x})|}{x^2}}^{-1}
$$
Is once again the product of a bounded function and a function converging to $0$ and thus $f(x)\stackrel{x\to0}{\to}0$.

Combining our cases yields:

- $\beta<0$ The function is nnot defined around $x=0$.
- $\beta=0$ or $\alpha=0$. The limit exists and is $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = \alpha$
- $\beta>0$ and $\alpha\neq0$. The limit does not exist.